# Shutdown a ThreadPoolExecutor before all tasks are finished

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a large list of strings (approx. 80,000), generate an HTTP request and process the responses until I get the correct one. I pass the list and a function that performs the request to a `ThreadPoolExecutor.map()` function and then iterate through the results as they come in.

Once the correct response is received from the HTTP server, I want to cancel all remaining futures and close the script. I'd prefer, for ease of programming, to not have to track every future myself.

I've tried using `shutdown()` but whether or not I specify to wait, the script still won't end until all queued futures are complete. As a result, if string 2000 of my list is the correct value I still have to wait for the next 78,000 futures to complete which could take a significant amount of time.

Is there a way to tell the ThreadPoolExecutor that the remaining tasks are unnecessary and that they don't even need to be started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can switch to Python 3.9, it's got this feature [built-in to the shutdown method](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown):

> If cancel_futures is True, this method will cancel all pending futures that the executor has not started running. Any futures that are completed or running won’t be cancelled, regardless of the value of cancel_futures.

Comment: I can't use 3.9 in my current environment but I think this is the probably the best answer in terms of meeting my requirement so I've accepted it as the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can `cancel()` futures. I see that you've indicated in the question that you don't like to track the futures, but it might be your best bet, and doesn't seem so hard:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time

def process(duration):
    print(f"processing with duration {duration}")
    time.sleep(duration)
    if duration == 3:
        return "result found"

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(process, i) for i in range(80000)]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        if future.result() == "result found":
            executor.shutdown(wait=False)
            print("shutdown")
            for f in futures:
                if not f.done():
                    f.cancel()
            break
print("about to exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `Event` object to control the execution of the *transform* function.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import threading

evt = threading.Event()
def transform(arg):
  if evt.is_set():
    return None

  ...
  return ret

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
  for result in pool.map(transform, data):
    if result == ...:
      evt.set()
      break
```